# linkedin people search api usage with Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linkedin-api

I tried using the following code to perform a people search in LinkedIn with ruby on rails:

```
client.search(
  :fields => [{ :people => %w(id first-name last-name api-standard-profile-request)}],
  :first-name =>  params["first_name"]
)
```

When executed it gives the following error:

`undefined local variable or method 'name' for #<JobsController:0x00000004888d68>`

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has to do with this line.

```rb
:first-name => params["first_name"]
```

In Ruby you can only have a minus sign in a symbol if the symbol is surrounded  with quotes. So instead of writing the symbol as `:first-name`, we would have to write it as `:'first-name'`. So our new code would be...

```rb
client.search(
  :fields => [{ :people => %w(id first-name last-name api-standard-profile-request)}],
  :'first-name' =>  params["first_name"]
)
```